# Formula equivalence as SMT file

Tags: z3, smt

I have SMT formulas as  can be seen from truth table:

I add two new variables as  d and e in order to define 3-sat problem.
The truth table gives same result for same a b c no matter the value of d and e.

[image]

I want to show this two formula gives same result as a SMT. So I write code below.
I have two question what is the wrong with my code, I guess it is true but it gives error.
Second question can I show this equilibrium even if there is two new variable. Thank you.

```
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(declare-fun c () Bool)
(declare-fun d () Bool)
(declare-fun e () Bool)

(define-fun fml1 () Bool
    (or (or a (or b (not c)))
    (and (or b (or c (not a)))
         (and (or d (or a (not b)))
            (and (or a (or (not b) (not d)))
                (and (or e (or a (not c)))
                    (and (or a (or (not e) (not c)))
)

(define-fun fml2 () Bool
    (implies (and (not a) (and (not b) c))
             (= a (or b c)))
)

(assert (distinct fml1 fml2))
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't properly closed all the parenthesis in your first formula, i.e., when you defined `fml1`. It should look like this:

```
(define-fun fml1 () Bool
    (or (or a (or b (not c)))
    (and (or b (or c (not a)))
         (and (or d (or a (not b)))
            (and (or a (or (not b) (not d)))
                (and (or e (or a (not c)))
                    (and (or a (or (not e) (not c)))))))))
)
```

Note the extra parenthesis to close the formula up, to balance the parenthesis. You should use an editor that can match parenthesis to alert you for such problems.

(Note that I haven't actually checked if you coded up the formulas properly. Just that the parenthesis match to close all the ones you started. As stated z3 produces `unsat` on this, suggesting `fml1` and `fml2` are equivalent indeed.)